# Adding attribute from the different table with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, concatenation

I am using Pandas to process table.

```
[table1]
  sample1 sample2 sample3
A 11      22      33
B 1       2       3

[table2]
  sample3 sample4 sample2
D 333     444     222

[Result]
  sample1 sample2 sample3
A 11      22      33
B 1       2       3
D NaN     222     333
```

I have two tables, and I want to add row `D` (of table 2) to table 1, considering the column name. If the column in table 1 exists in table 2, the corresponding value of `D` is added to table 1, like sample 2 and sample 3. If the column in table does not exist in table 2 like sample 1, the value of D is set to `NaN` or ignored.

Is there any simple way to do this with Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and then remove column `sample4` by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
print (pd.concat([table1, table2]).drop('sample4', axis=1))
   sample1  sample2  sample3
A     11.0       22       33
B      1.0        2        3
D      NaN      222      333
```

You can use [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) for selecting columns in both `DataFrames` and  then concat subset of `table2` by these columns:

```
print (table2.columns.intersection(table1.columns))
Index(['sample2', 'sample3'], dtype='object')

print (pd.concat([table1,table2[table2.columns.intersection(table1.columns)]]))
   sample1  sample2  sample3
A     11.0       22       33
B      1.0        2        3
D      NaN      222      333
```

Then if need remove rows with `NaN` use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
print (pd.concat([table1, table2]).drop('sample4', axis=1).dropna())
   sample1  sample2  sample3
A     11.0       22       33
B      1.0        2        3
```

Comment: I thought that I need to lookup values in columns, but concat is simpler and quite intuitive. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Glad can help you!

Answer (score 3):

You can generalize jezrael's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39404774/3635816) by first subselecting columns from `table2` which are in `table1`. This is quite neatly done using [`numpy.in1d`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39404774/3635816). This also avoids forming a potentially huge temporary data frame with columns from both data frames. Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

table1 = pd.DataFrame([[11, 22, 33], [1, 2, 3]], index=list('AB'), columns=['sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3'])
table2 = pd.DataFrame([[333, 444, 222]], index=['D'], columns=['sample3', 'sample4', 'sample2'])

# Sub-select columns...
cols_in_table1 = table2.columns[np.in1d(table2.columns, table1.columns)]

# ... and concatenate.
results = pd.concat((table1, table2[cols_in_table1]))

print(results)
```

Which prints:

```
   sample1  sample2  sample3
A     11.0       22       33
B      1.0        2        3
D      NaN      222      333
```

Comment: It would be very useful for subcolumn selection. Thank you for your comment about in1d function.